# Getting a PopUp while debugging an anonymous block in Oracle SQL Developer Tool

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I got an error while debugging an anonymous block in Oracle SQL Developer tool. It pops up a window saying unable to find the source file. But as this is an anonymous block, I don't need a source file. Even if I save that file and try again, it doesn't work anyway. (SQL Developer Version: 22.2.1) Here is the error I get:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: [Also asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74795247/266304) - different user but same image?

Comment: Take a look here:
https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/using-sql-developer-to-debug-your-anonymous-plsql-blocks/